# How to find the name of the method in Managed Code using Windbg and SOS?

Tags: windbg, .net

I've got a crash dump, the application definitely crash in JIT optimized assembler code. I know the start address of the method. How do I find its name using using Windbg and SOS extension?

Currently I'm just exploring each assembly in the domain, then in each assembly I dump all modules, then in each module I dump method tables hoping that some method address will be equal to the method I search. And it takes me eternity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`ip2md`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/sos-dll-sos-debugging-extension) sos command to get the method name for jitted code.

```
0:016> k
 # Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00 00000000`013fe688 00007ffb`4567ddb8 win32u!NtUserWaitMessage+0x14
01 00000000`013fe690 00007ffb`45611535 System_Windows_Forms_ni+0x2cddb8


0:016> !ip2md 00007ffb`45611535 
MethodDesc:   00007ffb454a25e8
Method Name:  System.Windows.Forms.Application+ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr, Int32, Int32)
Class:        00007ffb4540c9f8
MethodTable:  00007ffb45743f78
mdToken:      00000000060052f3
Module:       00007ffb453b1000
IsJitted:     yes
CodeAddr:     00007ffb45610fd0
Transparency: Safe critical
```